# Property 'schProd' does not exist on type '{} | { schProd: string; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code

```
interface faceMatch<P> {
  params: P;
  isExact: boolean;
  path: string;
  url: string;
}

const FormSearch: FC<{ match: faceMatch<{ schProd: string }|{}> }> = ({
  match
}) => {
  const [category, useCategory] = useState<string>("All");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
  useMemo(() => {
    if (Object.entries(match.params).length !== 0) {
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(match.params.schProd);
      searchParams.get("Search")
        ? setSearch(`${searchParams.get("Search")}`)
        : setSearch("");
    } else {
      setSearch("");
    }
  }, [match]);
return(...)
}
```

in line `if (typeof match.params.schProd === "string")` 
I get this error
Property 'schProd' does not exist on type '{} | { schProd: string; }'.
  Property 'schProd' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: `{ schProd: string }|{}` =>`{ schProd: string }||{}`?

Comment: @zynkn What did you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's pare this down to the [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
function fn(x: { a: string } | {}) {
  if (Object.keys(x).length !== 0) {
    x.a.charAt(0); // error! a does not exist on {}
  }
}
```

So, there are a few things going on here.  One is that the `{}` type [does not signify that there are no properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces).  Instead, it is one of the least restrictive types you could specify.  In fact, only `null` and `undefined` values do not match it:

```
{
  function takeEmpty(x: {}) {}
  const a = {}; takeEmpty(a); fn(a); // okay
  const b = { b: 123 }; takeEmpty(b); fn(b); // okay
  const c = "c"; takeEmpty(c); fn(c); // okay
  const d = ["d"]; takeEmpty(d); fn(d); // okay
  const e = function() {}; takeEmpty(e); fn(e); // okay
  const f = null; takeEmpty(e); fn(f); // error
  const g = undefined; takeEmpty(e); fn(g); // error
}
```

This might be surprising, but it is a natural consequence the fact that types in TypeScript are extendable/open, and not [exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)/closed.  This lets you extend interfaces by adding properties to them:

```
{
  interface A {
    a: string;
  }
  interface B extends A {
    b: string;
  }
  let a: A = { a: "hey" };
  let b: B = { a: "hey", b: "you" };
  a = b; // okay, because a B is also an A
}
```

And, as you can see, a value of type `A` doesn't stop being type `A` just because you add properties to it.  That means that the type `{}` is just a type with no *known* properties.

There isn't usually a way in TypeScript to directly represent an "exact" type having some known properties and no unknown properties.  But in the specific case of "a type with no properties at all", you can get close with something like this:

```
interface Empty {
  [k: string]: undefined;
}
```

That is using an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) to say that a value of type `Empty` can have any keys whatsoever (which is not exactly right) but that the values at those properties must be `undefined`.  So if we change `fn()` to take `{a: string} | Empty`, it will behave as expected when you call it:

```
function fn2(x: { a: string } | Empty) {
  // impl soon
}

{
  function takeEmpty(x: Empty) {}
  const a = {}; takeEmpty(a); fn2(a); // okay
  const b = { b: 123 }; takeEmpty(b); fn2(b); // error
}
```

So, that's great.

The bad news is, the implementation of `fn2()` still gives you an error:

```
function fn2(x: { a: string } | Empty) {
  if (Object.keys(x).length !== 0) {
    x.a.charAt(0); // error! object is possibly undefined ☹
  }
}
```

The error message is slightly different, but it's still basically complaining that maybe `x.a` doesn't exist.  But you checked it, didn't you?  Well, yes, but the compiler just doesn't see it that way.  Not all checking constructs are recognized as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types); there are only a few built-in ways to do this (although you can always [write your own function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to act as a type guard).  The easiest one to use in this case is probably a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards):

```
function fn3(x: { a: string } | Empty) {
  if (typeof x.a === "string") {
    x.a.charAt(0); // okay
  }
}
```

When we check `typeof x.a === "string"`, the compiler recognizes that inside the "then" clause, `x.a` must be a `string` and it lets you treat it as such.  Inside the "else" clause, if you had one, `x.a` would be narrowed to `undefined` instead.

That is probably a good place to stop for now.  Hope this helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAHgLkQb0QQ2wGcoAnGMAc0QF9EAfXGgSlwChFEZhFUB5AEYArAKbQAdAGsRATyIZm4gDYiqUABaIAhAF4diAAyscHTonTj84iOvykAglFRGA3IgD07xCNKk4pLQJEABM4ESJEMDgob3QYEkQEJlMaNlS2E05QSFgkqHxpAFEAWwAHKBkMbBwWZM4IBAT8RH0al1N8orKK1Hxmdqy0PrdPRMl8GVMGsASBFtxEAWwARgAmAGZaAcROkRLyyoF+0xRUI5GvOHHJ+saYiHmAIghH7d39nohjwdQvi7GJlM7iF5gBtR7BR4AXTeBT23UqwW+yDQSP+V0BtxmMRE82y0HgaGMNFhXQOqBEyNOlPR1yB2OQ8zAICUSlJ8PJNJOaGA-Q8Xh8flI9IS1H04GCImAFBEwXZH0qXJ+lD5o0F-jSbAypgoUB8wHwEFx9nYZgIxDIFEo21SnF1+sNuIAQrE9WBghETZkzEtECRyFQbaYVDFCIgTa1zYhHupZI8tsGRDFfS7I2GY3GADSLbCPGRwEDxkmmZr6AS0ibZgRifAgIi45ou+IEJREOAEJD2TVse2kA1GxAK02IUGSC0ByhQ7ASqUyuXd-G5JAoVZVBZh-1W2gMQcI4w6nj8YRiKBSWTydCKFRqTS6fRGYecCxWGx2RzOVUC3z+QJwY-QLgIlKOAiCIGABCUGREBnaUwFlRBAE4yFJu29RdCR2OEFTXBVjHMcQ5ltRBpiaeY2g6TCEV6KkwFXYZ+QBG4iOBOZI19NZNmLTh3ko856PVYVBlXXi1W-YV0jQpIUHWNc8A3S0qG3RgcOHbheAqUoRDgHhnxaPRo03KhHn3M1n2sWwHCcVx6IxRi6DSIA)

Comment: And what do you think will be the right decision if I change ` match: faceMatch<{ schProd: string }|{}>` to ` match: faceMatch<{ schProd?: string }>` ?.

Comment: I'm not saying that it does not work, but not the best solution to do so`match: faceMatch <{schProd ?: string}>`?.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking.  If you want to know whether you should use `{a?: string}` instead of `{a: string} | Empty` or `{a: string} | {}` you need to decide what values you want to accept and what values you want to reject.

Comment: Just saw a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310753/how-to-tell-a-typescript-that-value-is-an-empty-object) .In principle, I found the answer to my question.And thanks for the good explanation with an example

Answer (score 0):

Given the following parametric type

interface faceMatch

{
      params: P;
      isExact: boolean;
      path: string;
      url: string;
}

and instantiating it with `{ schProd: string } | {}` for `P`, we get

```
{
  params: {
    schProd: string
  } | {};
  isExact: boolean;
  path: string;
  url: string;
}
```

making the error easy to spot:

`{ schProd: string } | {}` is not `{ schProd: string | {} }`

Comment: as I understand match.params is either a string or an empty object.it follows that if I check match.params on Object.entries (match.params) .length! == 0 then match.params is not an empty object.For some reason, I get this error again in line `const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(match.params.schProd);`.

Comment: That's not a type guard and strings are objects

Comment: @ Aluan Haddad. Hello, I am new to typescript. I also encountered similar problems. I do not understand your explanation.can you give a small example or explain what needs to be done to make the error disappear.