# How to tell a typescript that value is an empty object?

Tags: typescript

Here is my code.

```
function DD(x: { y: string } | {}) {
  if (x.y) {//error
   console.log("DD jingo");
  }
}
```

I get this error  The property "y" does not exist in the type "{} | {y: string;}".The property "y" does not exist in the type "{}".

I am new to typescript. How to say that X can accept an empty object and {y: string}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the `y` property as optional, using `?`:

```
function DD(x: { y?: string }) {
  if (x.y) {
   console.log("DD jingo");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good pattern in TypeScript, but you could explicitly tell TypeScript that your value of `x` is of the type `{ y: string }` in your `if` statement:

```js
function DD(x: { y: string } | {}) {
  if ((x as {y: string}).y) {
   console.log("DD jingo");
  }
}
```